# Windows screencast software that allows to record screen and webcam simulteanously

Tags: windows, video, screen-recording, webcam

I need to find a Windows program that allows to record both an area of the screen **and** video from my webcam (preferably a small, resizable window I can place at the bottom of that area).

The exact same functionality is provided by Vokoscreen on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com/). It can use both, screen and webcam as a source and even pictures or text.

Here it is, a screenshot of the scene configuration with a monitor and a webcam as source (extra scary).

[image: OBS Screenshot]

The usability could probably be improved. Consider some time to get familiar with it and try it intensively before recording or streaming important videos.

There are at least 3 ways of adding things to a scene. To get started, I recommend:

1. start the preview
2. right click into the preview
3. Choose add > something

You can then click on an item and resize it or right click and change the properties.

Comment: thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately OBS didn't work on my laptop, but I'll give it a try on my desktop.